# Prevent dateInput from being NULL in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make it so that my dateInput only accepts the values in the dateInput drop down options and no others. For example, if a user tries to input nothing or delete the date, it returns to "1995-11-13". My code runs but when nothing is inputed, it remains as nothing instead of being change to "1995-11-13". What am I doing wrong?

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      h4("Date:"),
      dateInput("date", label = h5("Date input"), value = "1995-11-13")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    observeEvent(
      input$date,
      if(is.null(input$date)){
        updateDateInput(session, "date", value = "1995-11-13")
      }
    )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      h4("Date:"),
      dateInput("date", label = h5("Date input"), value = "1995-11-13")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){

    observeEvent(input$date,{
      if(length(input$date) == 0){
        updateDateInput(session, "date", value = "1995-11-13")
      }
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You said *"if a user tries to input nothing"*, that doesn't make the input an `NA`, but just a `NULL`. So there's where I'd start.

I would change the code from:

```
if(is.na(input$date)){
    updateDateInput(session, "date", value = "1995-11-13")
  }
```

To use `is.null()` instead:

```
if(is.null(input$date)){
    updateDateInput(session, "date", value = "1995-11-13")
  }
```